# Equality involving sums over permutations.

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, summation, permutations

Im reading [The Strong Law of Large Numbers for U-statistics by Wassily Hoeffding (1961)](https://repository.lib.ncsu.edu/bitstream/handle/1840.4/2128/ISMS_1961_302.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y).

Let $h:\mathcal{X}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ be any measurable mapping (i.e. in general non-permutation-symmetric in its arguments). It is stated that since the arithmetric mean mapping $g$ defined by
$$
(X_1,...,X_n) \stackrel{g}{\mapsto} \frac{(n-m)!}{n!}\sum_{1\leq i_1 \not = \cdots \not = i_m\leq n} h(X_{i_1},...,X_{i_m})
$$
is permutation-symmetric (in its arguments), each term may be placed by the arithmetric mean of the m! terms whose supscripts are permuations of the same set of integers. That is
$$
\frac{(n-m)!}{n!}\sum_{1\leq i_1 \not = \cdots \not = i_m\leq n} h(X_{i_1},...,X_{i_m})$$
$$
 =\frac{(n-m)!}{n!}\sum_{1\leq i_1 \not = \cdots \not = i_m\leq n} \frac{1}{m!} \sum_{\sigma\in \Pi_m}h(X_{i_{\sigma(1)}},...,X_{i_{\sigma(m)}}), 
$$
where $\Pi_m$ is the set of all permutations of $\{1,...,m\}$.

**Could anyone help me with this equality, I can't seem to tackle it?**

Comment: What is $h$?---

Comment: In case $(n,m)=(3,2)$, it seems it's saying that

$$h(X_1, X_2) + h(X_2, X_3) + h(X_1, X_3) = \frac{1}{2}(h(X_1, X_2) + h(X_2, X_1) + \dotsb + h(X_1, X_3) + h(X_3, X_1)) $$

Do you have any indication of why that would be true? Without knowing anything about $h$, it's not...

Comment: Maybe it's because the $X_i$ are supposed to be i.i.d. random variables? That will give us symmetry in $h$, no?

Comment: The first sum should be understood in the following way

$\sum_{1\leq i_1 \not = \cdots \not =i_m \leq n} =$ "the sum over all m-permutations $\{i_1,...,i_m\}$ of $\{1,...,n\}$"

Comment: @EricAuld In regards to the i.i.d. property that would only give equality in distribution. As to the case $(n,m)=(3,2)$ we have
$$
h(X_1,X_2)+h(X_2,X_1)+h(X_2,X_3)+h(X_3,X_2)+h(X_1,X_3)+h(X_3,X_1) = \frac{1}{2} (h(X_1,X_2)+h(X_2,X_1)+h(X_2,X_1)+h(X_1,X_2)+h(X_2,X_3)+h(X_3,X_2)+h(X_3,X_2)+h(X_2,X_3)+h(X_1,X_3)+h(X_3,X_1)+h(X_3,X_1)+h(X_1,X_3))
$$
which checks out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix an ordered sequence $(i_1, \ldots, i_m)$ with $i_j \in [n]$ all different. Let us define the sum over all permutations $\sigma \in \Pi_m$ by
\begin{equation}
S(i_1, \ldots, i_m) = \sum_{\sigma \in \Pi_m} h(X_{\sigma(i_1)}, \ldots, X_{\sigma(i_m)}).
\end{equation}
The sum in $S(i_1, \ldots, i_m)$ contains $h(X_{i_1}, \ldots, X_{i_m})$ as a term but also many other terms. Now, sum over all possibilities for $(i_1, \ldots, i_m)$ obtaining
\begin{equation}
\sum_{(i_1, \ldots, i_m)} S(i_1, \ldots, i_m)
\end{equation}

Notice that for a fixed $(j_1, \ldots, j_m)$ the term $h(X_{j_1}, \ldots, X_{j_m})$ will appear many times in this sum. More precisely, it will appear once for every $(i_1, \ldots, i_m)$ that is a permutation of $(j_1, \ldots, j_m)$ and there are $m!$ of them. Thus, we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{m!} \sum_{(i_1, \ldots, i_m)} S(i_1, \ldots, i_m) = \sum_{(j_1, \ldots, j_m)} h(X_{j_1}, \ldots, X_{j_m})
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks you very much Daniel, very good explanation.